# How can I get treemap datalabels to wrap consistently?

Tags: highcharts

I'm making a Highcharts treemap with some rather long datalabels. Sometimes they wrap, sometimes highcharts truncates them with ellipses (but it really seems like it could wrap them instead). The inconsistency makes it look a bit messy. Is there a way I can force the labels to always wrap?

Here is an example:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  colorAxis: {
    minColor: '#003A85',
    maxColor: '#F7F8FA',
    visible: false
  },

  series: [{
    type: "treemap",
    layoutAlgorithm: 'strip',
    layoutStartingDirection: 'horizontal',
    dataLabels: {
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      x: 5,
      y: 5,
      style: {
        textShadow: 'unset',
        textOutline: 'none',
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontWeight: 'normal',

      }
    },
    data: [{
      name: 'This is quite a long sentence really, oh well never mind',
      value: 4911,
      colorValue: 0
    }, {
      name: 'This is quite a long sentence really, oh well never mind',
      value: 3701,
      colorValue: 1
    }, {
      name: 'This is quite a long sentence really, oh well never mind',
      value: 3602,
      colorValue: 2
    }, {
      name: 'This is quite a long sentence really, oh well never mind',
      value: 3502,
      colorValue: 3
    }, {
      name: 'This is quite a long sentence really, oh well never mind',
      value: 3114,
      colorValue: 4
    }]
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        shadow: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Treemap'
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

[(image) Highcharts treemap with inconsistent label wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdyAT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More complex way to control text wrapping can be achieved when combined with the option for datalables, [useHTML: true](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.treemap.dataLabels.useHTML) and displaying [dataLabels.format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.treemap.dataLabels.format) as a string you can add your styles and customization there.

```
  plotOptions: {
    treemap: {
      dataLabels: {
        useHTML: true,
        format: '<p class="truncate"><b>{point.name}</b></a>',
        style: {
          textOverflow: 'allow'
        }
      }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zkwg2vnq/

Comment: After posting, I had fiddled with useHTML: true, but only in the series dataLabels, and I couldn't get it to work without missing labels or run-on text. Had no idea putting it in the plotOptions would have a different effect! Don't think I'd ever have found this so thank you very much!